# BASH: IF statement doesn't work with empty string from WHILE loop

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

The first `if` statement doesn't work if there is no output from the command. I also tried to evaluate the exit status but this also doesn't work?

`unhide-tcp` output:

```
# unhide-tcp 
Unhide-tcp 20130526
Copyright © 2013 Yago Jesus & Patrick Gouin
License GPLv3+ : GNU GPL version 3 or later
http://www.unhide-forensics.info
Used options: 
[*]Starting TCP checking

Found Hidden port that not appears in ss: 1025

Found Hidden port that not appears in ss: 1026
[*]Starting UDP checking
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unhide-tcp | grep "^Found" | while IFS=":" read -a PORT; do

        if [ -z ${PORT[1]} ]; then

            echo "No hidden ports found."

        elif [ -n ${PORT[1]} ]; then

            echo ${PORT[@]}

        fi

done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you simply need is:

```
unhide-tcp | grep "^Found" || echo "No hidden ports found."
```

It would print lines like `Found Hidden port that not appears in ss: 1025` and if those lines aren't found, script would print `"No hidden ports found."` instead - because `grep` returns nonzero if it doesn't find a match.

If you want to condense your output of ports into a single line, you can use `sed` and `readarray` with process substitution:

```
readarray -t PORTS < <(exec unhide-tcp | sed -nr 's|^Found.*: ([0-9]+).*|\1|p')
[[ ${#PORTS[@]} -gt 0 ]] && echo "${PORTS[@]}" || echo "No hidden ports found."
```

It could give an output like `1025 1026` or `No hidden ports found.`.

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off using `awk` like this:

```
unhide-tcp | awk -F':' '/Found/ && NF==2{c++; print} END{if (c==0) print "No hidden ports found"}'
```

When I used it on the input shown in your question I get this output:

```
Found Hidden port that not appears in ss: 1025
Found Hidden port that not appears in ss: 1026
```

Comment: There will be a different action based on the output so ideally I need these `IF` statements.

Comment: Sure you can use: `unhide-tcp | awk -F': *' '/Found/{ if (NF<2) print "No hidden ports found"; print $0 }'`

Comment: I just tested and I also don't get any output with `awk` if there are no any hidden ports.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by hidden port. Can you show a sample output of `unhide-tcp` for hidden ports?

Comment: Please see `unhide-tcp output:` section in the main question.

Comment: ok those 2 lines are being printed by awk. I attached output in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately "No hidden ports found" is not printed if `unhide-tcp` is not able to find any hidden ports (no output).

Comment: That is why I asked you to show a sample input for this condition. Do you want to print `No hidden ports found` **only once** if no line is found with hidden ports?

Answer (score 0):

Flags such as `-z` require an argument. In your example the expansion of the `$PORT` variable may be blank.  Wrap the variable name in double quotes.

> if [ -z "${PORT[1]}" ]; then ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this still doesn't work.